# Not achieving correct pixel width and height for map export in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-export

Trying to export the full extent of a EPSG:4326 layer of the earth (-180, 180,-90,90) with an exact pixel width (8192) and height (4096). I can't seem to get the width/height correct.
If I set the extent from the layer then adjust the dpi to get the right height then the width is a few pixels over which shows up as black border on the left and right of the final png.
If I force the correct width/height ratio (see image) then some of the extent gets cropped off.

Any clues?

[image]